# Using Google Analytics to track internal user behavior in Salesforce

Tags: google-analytics, event-monitoring

Can Google Analytics be used for tracking internal Salesforce users sessions?

We'd like to get an idea of common use paths--how are users interacting with our (largely custom development) Salesforce app? What tabs are they spending the most time? What elements of a record page are they clicking on most frequently? What errors are they hitting frequently? What are they searching for in Global Search?

All of my review of existing documentation talks about using Google Analytics on Salesforce Experience Sites, nothing really addressing implementation internally in an org. Is this something that could work to meet our requirements?

We've already concluded that Event Monitoring doesn't meet our requirements, but is there another tool anyone has used that would log data that effectively allows you to do a UX analysis on your org by collecting internal user session data?

Comment: https://medium.com/salesforce-architects/how-to-capture-ux-data-for-experience-driven-apps-on-salesforce-5ed96603c6af

Comment: @identigral Thanks, that's a super useful article! I'm still interested to hear if anyone has any experience with any ready-made AppExchange applications for this.